# Odoo /jsonrpc endpoint not found

Tags: odoo, localhost, json-rpc, odoo-13, odoo-rpc

Im trying to access my odoo database with odoorpc but I cant get it to work, I can`t even print out the databases on my odoo server. I tried it with this code:

```
import odoorpc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    odoo = odoorpc.ODOO("localhost", port=80, timeout=1200)
    print(odoo.version)
    odoo.login("db", "name", "password")
    print(odoo.db.list())
```

It works if I specify a single database with -d when starting the odoo server but that`s not possible because I need multiple databases, starting without a database filter works for my colleagues but just not for me. I keep getting this error in Python "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND" and this error in the odoo logs: "POST /jsonrpc HTTP/1.0" 404 - 1 0.002 0.006". Everything is the same, odoo.conf, starting command and code but it just doesnt work on my system.

I tried using everything my colleagues used, adding jsonrpc=True in my odoo.conf, trying every possible port and also trying to send a post request in postman but that didnt work too.

Comment: You should assign different ports to work with different databases.